# Overhead garage door opening on its own

Tags: doors, garage

I have two, 6 year old Overhead garage door openers. On about 5 occasions in the last couple of months, I have discovered one side has opened on its own. When this has happened, neither of the manual switches will function, but the RF openers will operate the door in either direction. I have checked the Safety Beam for obstructions and found none. Any ideas? I am thinking along the lines of an intermittent short in the circuit board of the opener but would welcome any thoughts or ideas.

Comment: You might be right; rain water or humididty may be finding it's way into the manual switch (shorting - open). But just to offer an alternative theory, maybe someone else in the neighborhood has a similar garage door opener (or TV remote that happens to operate on the same frequency), and they are (unwittingly) opening your garage.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it's intermittent makes it hard to prove. I suspect the manual switches you refer to are the type with a separate up button and down button rather than a single button type control. If that is the case then I suspect the up button (or the wires from it) has made a connection (short). That would explain it not working when you push the down button because the up is still in effect pushed. It could also be as you say a short in the board giving the signal to open. Some openers have a push button on the board also. I would try disconnecting the wires at the opener going to the manual controls. If it works for a month or two without any problems then I would replace the switches.

Comment: Well I doubt the theory that someone else is inadvertently operating a switch as one person suggested. For one, this is a "rolling code" so that makes it unlikely. The question of humidity causing the problem is a possibility although that would not explain why neither of the manual (single button type) operation wouldn't function while the RF units will make it work... I could see if one of the switches didn't function but seems unlikely that both manual switches would fail at the same time ... and then both begin working again at the same time... bizzare

Comment: @BGeoffreyBurnham The manual switches may very well be wired in parallel, so that closing either one will complete the circuit.  If this is the case, one bad switch would stop the functioning of the other, and JPC's answer makes sense. Next time it happens, disconnect one of the manual switches and see if the other works.  If not, reconnect the switch, disconnect the other one, and give it a try.

Comment: Great idea... both switches are wired separately to the main unit but I will give that a tray. I called Overhead Door company who wants $110 for the first 30 mins, then $20 for every 15 mins thereafter... with the likelihood of the opener functioning Correctly when they come out, it makes it very likely they would have to come out at least a second time.. for that cost, I can replace the entire unit myself... if it comes to that I am thinking about the Ryobi 2 HP opener... wondering if anyone has any experience with this unit .. Thanks again for your time and thoughts